# How to fix an autofill so it won't change after I change the cell it fills from

Tags: google-sheets

I want to simplify my time on Google Sheets. I am wondering if there are any formulaes out there that allows me to fill the cells on it's own with different numbers. I'll show you an example.[image]

As seen in the picture, I want to type in the selling price on Column A cells each time I get a sale and Column B will automatically fill itself. However, my cost price will vary , Cell F2, thus causing Cells G13 to G32 to change each time my cost changes.

Is there a way to make it so that whatever is filled becomes permanent and won't change despite what changed in Cells G13 to G32?

If you have other questions, please ask. I'll be happy to assist.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there a way to make it so that whatever is filled becomes permanent and won't change despite what changed in Cells G13 to G32?*

No... and yes.

**No**

A formula will always be dynamic so it will refer to the nominated cell(s) to complete a calculation. In your case, if there is only one cell containing the average cost , then the formula will adjust to that value, and not to the value that it was when the transaction took place.

The effect is that the cost in Column B will be unreliable. But...

**Yes**

The problem in this case is that there is a single cell for the average cost.

But what if, say, the items in Columns A&B correlate to specific transactions (by row) in the range F12:P32. And, what if you were to calculate the average cost on each transaction line. You might still use cell F2 to display, say, the "current" average cost. But when calculating the average in Column B, you would reference the cell in the corresponding Column/Row in the transaction range.